# How to convert specific Minecraft rig to cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

Dont laugh, I'm using Blender for Minecraft.

I'll cut to the chase. Ill provide details and the download for the rig im using. The rig is designed for the blender render engine, however I am trying to convert it to cycles. As you can see, the textures work fine in the blender render engine: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yuET.jpg

When switching to cycles mode, I need to reconfigure the textures. To make the skin reappear, I need to go to the materials tab, give the surface tab an image texture node with my skin in it.  I end up with something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/leiWX.jpg

The head remains untextured, and because it is labeled as an armature, Idk how to texture it in cycles. How was this armature head textured in blender render, but it cant in cycles?

Rig: https://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/83782